# How to simplify a sum with factorial?

Tags: summation

I have the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}, \quad k=9$$

[wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28factorial%28k%29/%28factorial%28n%29%2afactorial%28k-n%29%29%29,%20n=1%20to%20k,%20k%20=%209)

It got simplified to $2^k-1$. How can I do it with math formulas?
Thank you!

Comment: The function $\dfrac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}$ is often written $\binom k n$, and is called the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement), which states:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^k a^n b^{k-n} \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!} = (a+b)^k
$$

Use $a=b=1$, that is where the $2^k$ comes from.

The -1 is because the theorem includes the term when $n=0$, whereas in your question the summation only starts at $n=1$. So you must subtract the term when $n=0$, which is $1$, hence $-1$.

So $2k-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}=\binom{k}{n},\binom{k}{0}=1$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}=2^k$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}=-1+\binom{k}{0}+\sum_{n=1}^k \binom{k}{n}=-1+\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}=-1+2^k$$

Comment: I believe that it’s your second line that OP was asking about.